# Create sum of Elements that are not grouped by

Tags: mysql, aggregate

I'm trying to sum up all values from the values column by the timestamp "ts".

What I got so far:

```
select ts, item, value
from statistics
where indicator = "something"
```

### actual:

```
"1", "item1", "100"
"1", "item2", "200"
"1", "item3", "300"
"2", "item1", "101"
"2", "item2", "202"
"2", "item3", "303"
```

### expected:

```
"1", "item1", "100"
"1", "item2", "200"
"1", "item3", "300"
"1", "sum", "600"
"2", "item1", "101"
"2", "item2", "202"
"2", "item3", "303"
"2", "sum", "606"
```

Comment: Your query doesn't do any summing, why do you expect that?

Comment: You can use the `WITH ROLLUP` option to combine the sums with the original data.

Comment: I'd googled the `WITH ROLLUP` but to use it I'd need to `GROUP BY` to use it but I can't `GROUP BY` because I'd loose the details from how much an item contributes to the sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and `WITH ROLLUP`.

```
select ts, item, SUM(value)
from statistics
where indicator = "something"
GROUP BY ts, item WITH ROLLUP
```

You have to group by both columns to get the original rows in the result, then `WITH ROLLUP` adds the total lines. This will add a row with `item = NULL` for the `ts` totals, and a row at the end with both `ts = NULL, item = NULL` for the grand total.

Answer (score 1):

I think Barmar's solution should be accepted, but just for the sake of giving an alternative solution, I would describe this one:

```
select ts, item, value
from
(
(
select ts as ts, item, value
from statistics
where indicator = "something"
)
union
(
select ts as ts, 'zzzz_sum' as item, count(*) as value
from statistics
group by ts
)
) t
order by ts, item;
```

We basically union two result sets and order them accordingly